# Why does my website look like this on mobile devices?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently on a MacBook with the display dimensions of 15.4-inch (2880 x 1800) here is a screenshot of how each section of my website looks for my homepage.

**QUESTION 1**

How can I fix my `h3` text to ensure it's responsive on a mobile device. Here is a screenshot below of how it looks as you can see it doesn't adjust and fit on the screen correctly. If you look at the JSFIDDLE link to my site at the bottom of the post you can see I have used `<div class="col-lg-12">` to ensure it's responsive therefore, no idea why it's going this on mobile devices.

```
<h1 class="maintxt bounceInUp animated">Hi, welcome to my portfolio</h1>
<h2 class="maintxt bounceInUp animated">My name is Liam Docherty</h2>
<h3 class="cd-headline bounceInUp animated loading-bar">
   <span>I'm a</span>
   <span class="cd-words-wrapper">
   <b class="is-visible">Front-End Web Developer</b>
   <b>Graphic Designer</b>
   </span>
</h3>
```

Here is a screenshot of a mobile device view of my website showing the issue.

[image]

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wdafatrx/2/)

Comment: your markup in the fiddle has some issues as well.. you are missing an opening `<nav>` tag also your `<br/>` tags are terminated incorrectly

Comment: Having `.cd-words-wrapper b {white-space: nowrap;}` makes the title not to break on small devices

Comment: you have a lot of overrides that are "breaking" the default bootstrap behaviors.

Comment: @JonBridge Please consider editing out the request from others to improve your post, as it the OP's responsibility to make their question clear (And you explained your issue well). And as a recommendation for next time - Try to scope your questions about specific problem, and if you have more than one issue, then ask about them separately, so users that have a solution to only one of them could post an answer - Then you won't have to accept partial answers, or figure out which of the answers are the "most" correct

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks for the feedback, I have updated my post with only one of my issues which I'm having.

Comment: @JonBridge Thank you `:)` I really appreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set up Bootstrap [media querys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

```
@media (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 414px) {
 .cssClass1{
    margin-left:5px !important;
   }
 }
```

so each device with a width from 375 to 414px will take these special CSS classes. The width and height of the different devices can be chceked in the Responsive design Section from Safari. 320px is iPhone 5 and 375 is iPhone 6 and so on.

Check out your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdafatrx/3/) I changed the `font size` when the device is smaller than 375px to `0.5em`. Note that I used the `!important` keyword since sometimes its the Classes won't apply when you don't use the Keyword. Try it out yourself. That should do the trick if not leave a comment :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm trying to do the iPhone 6s + and iPhone 7. As a result of this do I replace the `px` value with their device `px` value?

Comment: No you can make multiple Media Querys. Like just under this one you go with `@media (min-width: 414px) and (max-width: 600px) {...` and define there the extra Css styling for devises with this width. You could do hundreds of media querys but of course its not recommended. Keep it simple